# MYSQL LEFT JOIN on each value JSON

Tags: mysql

Прошу помощи (mysql 5.7)
В связи с большим количеством данных в таблице было принято решение хранить связи ячеек не в отдельной таблице как обычно принято, а указывать их непосредственно напротив каждого поля в JSON

Есть таблица t1 в которой в поле vIDs хранятся ключи (50 штук) таблицы t2:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
.....
  `vIDs` json DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Таблица t2

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `vID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
.....
)
```

Необходимо сделать запрос к таблице t1 и вывести все связанные ключи из таблицы t2 которые хранятся в JSON t1.vIDs

```
EXPLAIN  SELECT t1.* FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  t2 ON JSON_CONTAINS(t1.vIDs->"$.*",JSON_ARRAY(t2.vID)) WHERE t1.ID=1
```

[image: EXPLAIN]

Данный запрос работает, но почему то идет проход по всем ключам из t2. И это не годится с текущим объемом базы.
Можно конечно сделать два запроса. В первом запроса Достать JSON из t1, разобрать его на php и Вторым запросом собрать все значения через IN или = и будет работать намного быстрее, но хочется эстетической красоты и уложить это все в 1 запрос.

Может возможно как то значения из t1.vIDs (JSON ключи) записать во временную таблицу и уже по ней делать JOIN?

Comment: *Может возможно как то значения из t1.vIDs (JSON ключи) записать во временную таблицу и уже по ней делать JOIN?* См. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255388/150107

Comment: @Akina Благодарю за помощь, уже видел данное решение, но оно меня не устраивает из за громоздкости и еще колличество  ключей vIDs всегда разное ( в среднем от 10 до 50). Я думаю то, что я хочу можно сделать через JSON_TABLE но к сожалению он есть только в mysql 8 и выше

Comment: Ну обновление сервера - не самое плохое решение, согласен. А других решений по конвертации JSON в таблицу без использования UDF я в общем особо и не видал. *оно меня не устраивает из за громоздкости* Ну громоздкое оно в основном из-за необходимости генерировать таблицу последовательных чисел, ибо в 5.7 нет также ни CTE, ни оконных функций. Помогает, конечно, статическая таблица чисел в служебной БД, или, например, `help_keyword_id` из `mysql.help_keyword`, если она заполнена.